# IBM CDC AS400 w/ Encryption

Tags: ibm-midrange, cdc, websphere

I would like to confirm whether it is possible to have encrypted data transfer from AS400 to the target as Apache Kafka on a cloud.  As far as I know, there is no such option for IBM Series-i but available on Linux and Windows.

So, it is not possible to configure IBM data replication (CDC) with:

AS400 (Journal) -> Access Server / Apply Agent -> Kafka on AWS

There is a big concerns for the security for MQ w/o encryption.  Even there is a secured tunnel, but it is not allowed to have un-encrypted message (only the VPN is secure).  Actually, I am still thinking of any possible workaround for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a developer with the IBM CDC team.

Regarding AS400 encrypted data transfer, there is no such option available at the moment. However, we do have a Request for Feature Enhancement (RFE) to enable this scenario: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=45264. The development team will prioritize this feature enhancement based on customer interest.

Regarding security concerns, one option could be keeping all of the CDC components in the datacenter, behind a firewall and secured, and apply to Kafka using remote TLS connection.

CDC uses Kafka 1.1.1 client library to write to Kafka. If Kafka on AWS supports this jar as a producer, then CDC can write to it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am thinking of using Kafka 1.1.1 client library to write to Kafka.  (AWS Kafka cluster target).  However, I am thinking whether it is an encrypted message.  I am thinking about writing to a local Kafka at the local CDC.  Then, to call the Kafka with TLS to the remote AWS Kafka.

Unfortunately, I am still seeking for any IBM CDC documentations with further details on the CDC Kafka

Comment: By default, Apache Kafka communicates in PLAINTEXT, which means that all data is sent in the clear. To encrypt communication, you should configure all the Kafka components in your deployment to use SSL encryption. Or configure AWS Kafka to use SSL. Here's a Confluent link for configuring SSL: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html 

Once that is set up, you can configure CDC for Kafka engine to replicate directly to this secure Kafka. Here's a pdf on how to do that: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-cdc-replication-engine-kafka-use-ssl-security

Comment: Then, I have update the JAAS with failed to load SSLkeystore.  I think I have created the JAAS file with client entry correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to this older thread in case it is still relevant for OP or others. Our recently released product https://www.infoviewsystems.com/infocdc/ enables the journal based replication and end to end encryption from IBM i (AS400) -> Kafka Connect connector -> Kafka platform on any hosted environment (AWS, Confluent Cloud etc).